# How to batch list into a single bytes object?

Tags: solidity, bytes, abiencoderv2

Let's say I have a string list of parameters

`["Example String", "vitalikbuterin", "1000"]`

How can I encode this list into a bytes object, and then decode the bytes to get the exact same list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could convert string arrays to bytes where each byte is a character and you can use byte `0x00` as a separator.

Here's a contract with the 2 methods you need to pack or unpack a `string[] memory` to/from a `bytes memory`

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity 0.8.18;

contract StringsAndBytes {
    function packString(string[] memory list) external pure returns (bytes memory){
        bytes memory packedArray;
        if (list.length == 0) {
            return packedArray;
        }
        packedArray = abi.encodePacked(list[0]);
        for (uint i = 1; i < list.length; i++) {
            packedArray = abi.encodePacked(packedArray, hex"00", list[i]);
        }
        return packedArray;
    }

    function unpackString(bytes memory pack) external pure returns (string[] memory) {
        if (pack.length == 0) {
            string[] memory emptyArray;
            return emptyArray;
        }
        uint256 elementCount = 1;
        for (uint i = 0; i < pack.length; i++) {
            if (pack[i] == 0x00) {
                elementCount++;
            }
        }
        string[] memory list = new string[](elementCount);
        uint256 arrayIndex = 0;
        string memory element = "";
        for (uint i = 0; i < pack.length; i++) {
            if (pack[i] == 0x00) {
                list[arrayIndex] = element;
                element = "";
                arrayIndex++;
                continue;
            }
            element = string(abi.encodePacked(element, pack[i]));
        }
        list[arrayIndex] = element;
        return list;
    }
}
```

Now if I call

```js
packString(["Example String", "vitalikbuterin", "1000"])
```

I get: `0x4578616d706c6520537472696e6700766974616c696b6275746572696e0031303030`

Then i can call

```js
unpackString("0x4578616d706c6520537472696e6700766974616c696b6275746572696e0031303030")
```

I get `["Example String", "vitalikbuterin", "1000"]`

### Edit: Simpler but non-packed

I had never used `abi.decode` before in my life. I made this answer, then I thought I'd ask an AI that shall not be named, it gave me a much simpler almost working code (that I fixed) but the resulting bytes end up with a lot of zeroes:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract StringsAndBytesByAI {
    function encodeStringList(string[] memory stringList) public pure returns (bytes memory) {
        return abi.encode(stringList);
    }

    function decodeStringList(bytes memory encodedList) public pure returns (string[] memory) {
        string[] memory decodedList = abi.decode(encodedList, (string[]));
        
        return decodedList;
    }
}
```

calling

```js
encodeStringList(["Example String", "vitalikbuterin", "1000"])
```

gives the following result:

`0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000e0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000e4578616d706c6520537472696e67000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000e766974616c696b6275746572696e00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000043130303000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`

And it can be reversed:

```js
decodeStringList("0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000e0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000e4578616d706c6520537472696e67000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000e766974616c696b6275746572696e00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000043130303000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000")
```

Result: `["Example String", "vitalikbuterin", "1000"]`

If you need to optimize for storage, use the first one, if you need to optimize for computation, use the second one.

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can use this website to encode
https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-decimal.html

Answer (score 0):

Batching a list into a single bytes object can be done by using the encode_abi() function from Solidity. This function takes a list of elements and returns a bytes object with the data stored in the proper format.

Comment: Are you confusing it with `_abi_encode()` from Vyper? It's called `abi.encode()` in Solidity.

Answer (score 0):

To batch list into a single bytes object, you can use the "bytearray" function in Python. This function takes a list of values and returns a bytes object.

For example, if you have a list of numbers such as [1,2,3,4], you can create a bytes object using this code:

bytearray([1,2,3,4])

This will return a bytes object containing the values 1,2,3,4.